# Scala Phantom Cassandra Conditional insert?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am using Phantom library to insert rows from my Scala code into Cassandra.

So basically I create a class which extends the CassandraTable and then I get all the create, update methods from the phantom library.

One thing I want to know is how does it generate its INSERT statements. Does it generate a vanilla INSERT statement of a conditional update statement like INSERT IF NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just log the query and the response would be obvious. By default the `insert` query does NOT contain `ifNotExists`. As of Phantom 2.5.0, tables auto-generate a `store` method so you can call:

```
database.table.store(record).ifNotExists.future()
```

Before phantom 2.5.0:

```
def store(record: Record): InsertQuery.Default[Table, Record] = {
  insert.value(_.column1, record.value1)
    .value(_.column2, record.value2)
    ...
    .ifNotExists()
}
```

On a side note, all queries in phantom have a `.qb.queryString` accessor on them so it's pretty trivial to look inside.